# Gcloud unable to detach disk by cli - disk does not exist in zone error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm getting an error trying to detach a disk from a GCP instance with the CLI:

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk dev-sql --disk=dev-sql-data-disk --zone us-east1-b
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.detach-disk) Disk [dev-sql-data-disk] is not attached to instance [dev-sql] in zone [us-east1-b].
```

When I look at the properties of the disk I am trying to attach it tells me that it's in zone the zone I am asking for:

```
Properties
Type
Regional SSD persistent disk
Size 
1536 GB
Zones
us-east1-b, us-east1-c # <-- the disk is in zone us-east-1-b
Labels
None
In use by
dev-sql
Snapshot schedule
None
Source snapshot
dev-sql-data-disk-snapshot
Encryption type
Google managed
```

In the properties it's telling me that the disk is in zone `us-east-1-b` and `us-east-1-c`.

So why is this command failing? How can I detach this disk on the CLI?

Comment: Either use `--disk-scope=regional` or --disk=FULL_URI` and remove the `--zone` option.

Comment: Can you also post the result of `gcloud compute disks describe`? And also add `--verbosity` when detaching?

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify both `--disk-scope` and `--zone` in order for this to work:

```
    gcloud compute instances detach-disk dev-sql --disk=dev-sql-data-disk --zone=us-east1-b
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/btgcp-iaas-dev/zones/us-east1-b/instances/dev-sql-td].
```

Thanks to everyone who commented.